Brownie not identifying network:'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
I am not able to specify the network name in brownie run.
brownie run ./scripts/deployment_v2.py --network mainnet
brownie run ./scripts/deployment_v2.py --network ropsten

Error message:

'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Error log:

PolygonFlashloanArbBotProject is the active project.   File
"C:\Users\ADMIN\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\Lib\site-packages\brownie_cli_main_.py",
line 62, in main
importlib.import_module(f"brownie._cli.{cmd}").main()   File "C:\Users\ADMIN\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\Lib\site-packages\brownie_cli\run.py",
line 45, in main
network.connect(CONFIG.argv["network"])   File "C:\Users\ADMIN\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\Lib\site-packages\brownie\network\main.py",
line 31, in connect    active = CONFIG.set_active_network(network)
File
"C:\Users\ADMIN\pipx\venvs\eth-brownie\Lib\site-packages\brownie_config.py",
line 78, in set_active_network
network["settings"] = self.settings["networks"][key].copy() TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Thanks,
Uday
